# How to compare 3 columns for a particular row & assign the max value to 4th column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table t with following structure -

```
ColumnX|ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC
-------------------------------
80% A  |80% A  |10% B  |10% C
```

In above table, all 4 columns are varchar & ColumnA, B & C will have the same value format i.e, 'x% xyz'. I want to compare the percentage value part & whichever column out of A, B & C is the max for a partcular row, get the whole value & assign to ColumnX in that row (as the example shows above).

How do i go about this? i tried using the value(v) method but i'm stuck at how i can get the whole value & not just the percentage part which i'm using to compare.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is rather painful.  Why are you storing percentages as strings?

Let's extract the numbers and do a giant case:

```
select (case when a_int >= b_int and a_int >= c_int then a
             when b_int >= c_int then b
             else c
        end) as x,
       t.*
from t outer apply
     (values (cast(left(a, charindex('%', a) - 1) as int),
              cast(left(b, charindex('%', b) - 1) as int),
              cast(left(c, charindex('%', c) - 1) as int)
             )
     ) v(a_int, b_int, c_int);
```

For an update, you can basically use this as a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select (case when a_int >= b_int and a_int >= c_int then a
                   when b_int >= c_int then b
                   else c
              end) as new_x,
             t.*
      from t outer apply
           (values (cast(left(a, charindex('%', a) - 1) as int),
                    cast(left(b, charindex('%', b) - 1) as int),
                    cast(left(c, charindex('%', c) - 1) as int)
                   )
           ) v(a_int, b_int, c_int)
     )
update toupdate
    set x = new_x;
```